# How do I move a product div from left or right and up or down using And Store its position

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

How do I move a product div from left or right and up or down using And Store its position for next time visit

I want to move div with some animation and sequence it and store in using php

Buttons

```
            <button type="button" href="#addProductModel"  data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success card-link px-2!important" style="width: 78px;background-color: #3CB371;border-color: #3CB371 ;color: #302D45">Add</button>
            <button type="button" id="btn-edit-product" class="btn btn-danger" href="#editProductModel" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success card-link px-2!important" style="width: 78px;background-color:#FF7F50;border-color: #FF7F50 ;color: #302D45">Edit</button>
            <span> </span>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" style="margin-left:30px" >Row Up</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" >Row Down</button>
            <button id="btn_left" type="button" class="btn btn-dark" style="width: 78px;">Left</button>
            <button id="btn_right" type="button" class="btn btn-dark" style="width: 78px;">Right</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"  data-toggle="modal" onclick="fn_delete_img();" style="width: 78px;margin-left:30px;color: #302D45;background-color: #FF6347;border-color: #FF6347">Delete</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="fn_hide_img();" style="width: 78px;background-color: #FFA500;border-color: #FFA500">Hide</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="fn_show_img();"  style="width: 78px;background-color: #FFA500;border-color: #FFA500">show</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 78px;color: black">Report</button>
```

Here is Product fetch from database

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row" style="color:#FA5C43;font-family:Impact;font-size:24px;">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
         Products
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <?php foreach ( $fetchproduct as $prodduct):?>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xm-3 col-xl-3 col-xs-3" style="padding-top: 23px" id="<?php echo $prodduct->pid;?>">
         <div class="card">
            <!-- <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="check1" style="margin-left: 10px;margin-top: 10px" /> -->
            <input type="checkbox"  name="product_checkbox" class="product_checkbox" id="product_checkbox_<?php echo $prodduct->pid;?>" value="<?php echo $prodduct->pid; ?>" style="margin-left: 8px; margin-top: 8px; position: absolute;left: 0px;top: 0px;"/>
            <img src="<?php echo base_url();echo $prodduct->p_imgthumburl?>" class="card-img-top" alt="">
            <div class="card-body" style="text-align:center;background-color: #303030;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px; height: 170px;">
               <strong style="color:#DCDCDC;font-family:Arial;font-size:19px;"><?php echo $prodduct->p_name_en ;?></strong><br>
               <strong class="card-text" style="color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;"><?php echo $prodduct->p_description_en ;?></strong>

            </div>
         </div>
      </div>

  <?php endforeach;?>
  </div>
</div>
```

I did for a left button with a swap function

```
<script>

    $.fn.swapWith = function(that) {
          var $this = this;
          var $that = $(that);
          // create temporary placeholder
          var $temp = $("<div>");
          // 3-step swap
          $this.before($temp);
          $that.before($this);
          $temp.after($that).remove();
          console.log('swap');
          return $this;
        }

    $('#btn_left').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        /* Act on the event */
        console.log("InsideLeft Button");
        var currentCheckBoxId = $('input[name=product_checkbox]:checked').val();
        var currentDivId=$("#"+currentCheckBoxId).parent().parent().attr('id');
        var swapCheckBoxId="product_checkbox_4";
        var swapDivId=$("#"+swapCheckBoxId).parent().parent().attr('id');

        $("#"+currentDivId).swapWith("#"+swapDivId);

    });

</script>
```

Comment: i'd suggest looking in to jquery sortable

Comment: did you make some r&d about drag and drop feature of jquery?

Comment: Yes, but I want to do with the button click not drag and drop @Gulshan

Comment: with jQuery Sortable @Alex

Comment: you can try CSS animation by updating the element property

Comment: Here some snippnet https://codepen.io/osublake/pen/RNLdpz https://codepen.io/francisco/pen/drbHq

Comment: how can I achieve this with button click event for left and right to buttons with checkbox selection

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#moveleft').click(function() {
        $('#textbox').animate({
        'marginLeft' : "-=30px" //moves left
        });
    });
    $('#moveright').click(function() {
        $('#textbox').animate({
        'marginLeft' : "+=30px" //moves right
        });
    });
    $('#movedown').click(function() {
        $('#textbox').animate({
        'marginTop' : "+=30px" //moves down
        });
    });
    $('#moveup').click(function() {
        $('#textbox').animate({
        'marginTop' : "-=30px" //moves up
        });
    });
});
</script>

<div style="padding:20px;"> <button id="moveleft">Move Left</button>  <button id="moveright">Move right</button> <button id="movedown">Move Down</button> <button id="moveup">Move Up</button></div>
<div id="textbox" style="position:absolute;padding:10px;background:#FFFFCC;width:300px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas nec tincidunt purus. Donec eleifend libero in orci mattis pulvinar. Ut et felis eu leo malesuada eleifend. Ut sit amet odio eu ipsum rutrum consequat. Aliquam congue ultricies sagittis.</div>
```

Go through below url for reference: https://www.sanwebe.com/2011/12/jquery-move-div-leftrightupdown

Comment: its animation but what I want to achieve that move div element from the first div to another div

Comment: How your divs will be placed?, so that you can move content to left, right, top, down etc..

Comment: divs are normal and it has unique checkbox selection and parent div has the unique id as well